# sending serial commands to SimpleBGC on Raspi in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

**Back story:** As the title suggests, what I'm trying to do is send serial commands to a gimbal board called the "SimpleBGC32 Extended" and receive real time data back. There is documentation and examples regarding this topic, but the examples revolve around a library that doesn't support python 2.7.9 (which I have to use for compatibility) and I can't reverse engineer them on my own. After trying to send lots of commands, I'm putting my pride aside and asking the experts.

**Documentation:**[Serial API](https://www.basecamelectronics.com/files/SimpleBGC_2_6_Serial_Protocol_Specification.pdf)
In the documentation, it has a description of all of the possible data to retrieve, as well as the format of the messages. The Format page looks like Command Format

[image].

The command I'm interested in sending is Command Data Image

[image]

Where the format is Command Header

[image].

I'm trying to retrieve real time IMU Data ("IMU_ANGLE[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs8FK.jpg)") from the command section "CMD_REALTIME_DATA_3" The format of the message is described in the image above, and that's the part I've been struggling with.

**Code**: This is what code I have so far. I have imported the library, opened the serial port to the baudrate it prefers, and have a loop setup. The part I'm stuck on is how to declare the message, and how to send it (serial.write command). *This example is to be written in python 2.7.9 using the pyserial library.*

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200)
while True:
   ser.write(#what do I put here?)
   try: 
      data = ser.readline() #retrieve IMU Data once the command sends and gimbal replies
   except:
      print "loading"
```

I really appreciate any help you guys can offer, I understand there are similar examples, but nothing I could find explained how to use this format without a library.

Comment: Bad technical PDF ! like this : `Header checksum` not an part of `header`, it's `member of header`.  **Example: outgoing command to read Profile2:** `ser.write("\x3E\x52\x01\x53\x01\x01")`

Comment: @dsgdfg Since the CMD_REALTIME_DATA_3 is defined as command id 23, and it is a 2byte unsigned data type, would I send: `ser.write("\x3E\x17\x02?\x44\x02\x20")` I guessed that the 2s data type would send a 0x02? and then used this calculator to find the checksum, and then converted the checksum8 modulo 256 output to hex. Is this right? Calculator link: https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/

Comment: you figure this out?